# Nagios で HTTP コンテンツが変更されたことを検知したい

Tags: linux, http, monitoring

Nagios を使って HTTP や HTTPS のコンテンツが変更されたことを
検知する仕組みはどのようにすれば実現できるでしょうか。

check_http には次のオプションがあり、「指定した時間より古い場合に警告」という動作をします。

```
-M, --max-age=SECONDS
```

これとは逆に「新しい場合に警告」という動作ができれば問題を解決できると思っていますが実現方法がわかりません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nagiosのpluginはしかるべきステータスコードを返すプログラムというだけなので、たいていのことはちょっとしたシェルスクリプト程度で監視できます。

```sh
#!/bin/sh

HOST=$1
URL=$2

SAVE=/var/tmp/${HOST}

new_data=`curl -s $URL |sha256sum`
new_data=`echo $new_data` #空白よけ

if [ ! -e $SAVE ]; then
    status=3 #UNKNOWN
else
    old_data=`cat $SAVE`

    if [ "$old_data" = "$new_data" ]; then
        status=0 #OK
    else
        status=2 #CRITICAL
    fi
fi

echo $new_data > $SAVE
exit $status
```

Comment: Exit ステータスが 監視ステータスになるんですね。
目的の監視が実現出来ました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

別途、"wget -N" などでコンテンツをダウンロードしてから check_file_age でどうでしょうか。

あるいは、ハッシュ値などを計算・保存しておいて、前回のものと比べる方法が考えられます。
Nagios は過去の値を保存して比較するような用途には向いていませんが、プラグイン側で工夫すればできそうです。

直接ファイルを参照できるのであれば、Tripwire, AIDE などの改竄検知ツールが良いと思います。

Comment: "wget -N" だとファイルのタイムスタンプがWebサーバーと同じになりました。
"check_file_age" のしきい値が秒数なので目的に動作にはなりませんでした。

ハッシュ値の計算・保存については、試してませんが実現出来そうです。
ありがとうございます。